# CSS3 animation is not working in Firefox

Tags: css, animation, transform

This works fine in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox. How do I fix it?

```
@keyframes rotate {
        0% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
                -moz-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
                -o-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
                -ms-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
                transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
        }

        100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,360deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
                -moz-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,360deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
                -o-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,360deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
                -ms-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,360deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
                transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,360deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
        }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vahidseo/qYJHm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781701) this is a bug with the number of deg option in firefox

working fiddle (also in Firefox) with different number (120 and not 360)

http://jsfiddle.net/qYJHm/5/

```
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
        -moz-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
        -o-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
        -ms-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
        transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,120deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
        -moz-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,120deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
        -o-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,120deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
        -ms-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,120deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
        transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,120deg) translate3d(100px,100px,100px);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, the blurry animation is not working either. And I want the dice to rotate all the way around.